# How do I import this file into VueJS?

Tags: javascript, node.js, vue.js, module

I have this file which looks like it was written in fairly outdated syntax that I want to include in a VueJS Component. The link to the file is [here](https://github.com/cryptoqween/cryptoqween.github.io/blob/master/streamer/ccc-streamer-utilities.js).

For example, take a look at these lines from the file:

```
var CCC = CCC || {};
CCC.STATIC = CCC.STATIC || {};

CCC.STATIC.TYPE = {
  'TRADE': '0',
  'FEEDNEWS': '1',
  'CURRENT': '2',
  'LOADCOMPLATE': '3',
  'COINPAIRS': '4',
  'CURRENTAGG': '5',
  'TOPLIST': '6',
  'TOPLISTCHANGE': '7',
  'ORDERBOOK': '8',
  'FULLORDERBOOK': '9',
  'ACTIVATION': '10',
  'FULLVOLUME': '11',
  'TRADECATCHUP': '100',
  'NEWSCATCHUP': '101',
  'TRADECATCHUPCOMPLETE': '300',
  'NEWSCATCHUPCOMPLETE': '301'
};
```

In my component, I need to be able to write things like

```
if (messageType == CCC.STATIC.TYPE.CURRENTAGG) { foobar(message) }
```

How would I go about importing the file into my component in a way through which I can reference it's declarations cleanly?

Comment: It really depends on how you're using Vue - with which version of JS and how you typically import other files :)

Comment: @AndreyPopov I import modules into the component kind of like this:

import axios from 'axios'

Comment: So you're using ES6 or something newer? Then dig up how [importing](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/import) and [exporting](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/export) works ;)

Comment: Hi @RohanKapur isn't that enough to copy the js content in another js file wrapped with an export?

Comment: @P3trur0 Whenever I type 'CCC.anything' anywhere in my code, it says 'cannot read property of undefined'

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can copy the content of [the original js file](https://raw.githubusercontent.com/cryptoqween/cryptoqween.github.io/master/streamer/ccc-streamer-utilities.js) in another file of your application, let's say: `embellished-ccc-streamer-utilities.js`.

Then, as final row of this new file you can add the following line:

```
  export default CCC
```

This basically exports the `CCC` object to make it available in other modules of your application.

Indeed, after this minor embellishment of the original file, you can import it as a normal module, like this:

```
import CCC from './embellished-ccc-streamer-utilities.js'
```

and use it according to your needs, for example:

```
if (messageType == CCC.STATIC.TYPE.CURRENTAGG) { foobar(message) }
```

Answer (score 1):

Add the following as `data.js` [I have removed the semi-colons and the use of `CCC` before it was declared, to shut up my linter :-)]

```
var CCC = {}
CCC.STATIC = CCC.STATIC || {}

CCC.STATIC.TYPE = {
  'TRADE': '0',
  'FEEDNEWS': '1',
  'CURRENT': '2',
  ...
  ...
  'NEWSCATCHUPCOMPLETE': '301'
}

export default CCC
```

And in your component you go:

```
import CCC from './data.js' // adjust the path accordingly
...
...
mounted () {
    ...
    console.log(CCC.STATIC)
    console.log(CCC.STATIC.TYPE.TRADE)
}
```

Please check out the Examples section here: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/import

Hope this helps.